# Writing non-GUI JUnit test cases for an app that relies on the SWT event loop being pumped on OS X?

Tags: java, macos, unit-testing, junit, swt

I'm working on an SWT-based application on OS X, and I'd like to write some JUnit test cases (*not* automated GUI tests) on some utility code that requires the SWT event loop being pumped, but not necessarily the presence of a GUI.  I'm running in to a lot of problems.

As a condensed example of some of the trouble code: I have a small repeating SWT timer utility loosely based on the following pattern:

```
public class RepeatingSWTTimer
{
    private boolean isRunning = false;
    private RepeatingSWTTimerAction timerAction;
    private int delay;

    private Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            timerAction.fire();
            if(isRunning)
            {
                Display.getCurrent().timerExec(delay, this);
            }
        }
    };

    public void start()
    {
        isRunning = true;
        Display.getCurrent().timerExec(delay, timerRunnable);
    }
}
```

The code works just fine, and the actual class has a lot more to it than just one method, and I use it in a lot of places in my application without issue.  But I still want to cover it with a test case.

The main issues I'm having are:

1. If there is no Display instantiated (such as in calling `Display.getDefault()` in `@BeforeClass`), then `Display.getCurrent()` will return a Null Pointer.
2. If there is a Display instantiated but no boiler-plate loop code (`while(!shell.isDisposed())...`, etc.) then the event loop doesn't seem to get pumped by the underlying native system.
3. If I do open a simple shell in `@BeforeClass`, it blocks the JUnit test cases.  They won't run until I close the shell, which brings me back to my original issue.  I'm assuming this is due to the `-XstartOnFirstThread` requirement of OS X.

I know that there are tools like `SWTBot` for automated *GUI* testing with SWT, but I just need some simple JUnit cases to cover my non-GUI utility code.

Has anyone out there experienced anything like this?

Comment: How are you creating the Shell instance?  new Shell(Display.getDefault())?

Comment: @sharakan `Display display = Display.getDefault(); Shell shell = new Shell(display);`, so yes.